# Modify DropdownList MVC using users?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

It turns out that I have a Jquery from a dropdownlist in casacade, this contains data from districts and services and I want that when a user logs in, only shows the data of the district where the user is from, the user has an assigned district.

This is my code on the controller:

```
public JsonResult GetServices(int districtId)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var services = db.Services.Where(s => s.DistrictId == districtId).OrderBy(s => s.Name);
        return Json(services);
    }
```

This is my Jquery Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#DistrictId").change(function () {
           $("#ServiceId").empty();
           $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: '@Url.Action("GetServices")',
               dataType: 'json',
               data: { districtId: $("#DistrictId").val() },
               success: function (districts) {
                   $.each(districts, function (i, service) {
                       $("#ServiceId").append('<option value="'
                           + service.ServiceId + '">'
                           + service.Name + '</option>');
                   });
               },
               error: function (ex) {
                   alert('Failed to retrieve services.' + ex);
               }
           });
           return false;
       })
   });
</script>
```

My View:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DistrictId, "District", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("DistrictId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DistrictId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServiceId, "Service", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ServiceId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ServiceId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: In the controller, you will need to get a reference to the current user (userId) and pass that value in the linq query to also filter by userId

Comment: Add a `Where` condition to your LINQ query to get data only for the userId. Without knowing your data model schema, It is hard to give you a specific answer.

Comment: I would suggest clarifying what your question/intent is.  The information you have provided is good, maybe add a little more info about your data model schema as @Shyju said.

Comment: Unrelated note about the [tag:visual-studio]. If you read the description, it says *DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio.*, so it should not be used in this question.

Comment: Thanks I have these models users, districts and services, I have another model called fevers where users enter number of patients and number of patients with fever, the latter model requires district information and service. In the user model, it requires name, surname, user name, which is the email address and also requires which district and service they belong to. With all this, what I want to do is that when the user logs in, only the services of the user's district are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the logged user is consuming the controller method. You can obtain the user and filter by his district id without sending it as a parameter. If you have both dropdowns in the same View, what you are doing seems to be OK. If the problem is that it never goes inside the method, be sure you are using the corresponding Http Verb in this case POST.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetUserServices()
{
    var user = userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    var services = db.Services
                    .Where(s => s.DistrictId == user.DistrictId)
                    .OrderBy(s => s.Name);
    return Json(services);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I have these models users, districts and services, I have another model called fevers where users enter number of patients and number of patients with fever, the latter model requires district information and service. In the user model, it requires name, surname, user name, which is the email address and also requires which district and service they belong to. With all this, what I want to do is that when the user logs in, only the services of the user's district are loaded.